# Não consigo dar build no app iOS para publicação

Tags: ios, xamarin, apple

Quando tento dar um Build no meu App(IOS), diz que não tem o Provisioning Profile. Eu fiz todo o passo a passo na Apple Store, tipo> AppID(Profile), Certificate(Development e Production) e as distribuições AdHoc e AppleStore. Veja como está o meu Provisioning Profile nas propriedades do projeto IOS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que em Provisioning Profile está como

> No Match Profiles found

e deveria ter uma lista de Profiles, ou pelo menos um.

Uso Visual Studio 2019 for Mac

Comment: Aconselho fortemente dar uma olhada nesse site: [Certificado e Provisioning Profile](https://www.lambda3.com.br/2017/08/entendendo-certificados-e-provisioning-profiles-do-ios/) Nele você vai entender mais sobre o fluxo de distribuição para iOS.

Comment: Você baixou os certificados? Você gerou a assinatura? Você configurou no painel online tudo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, sim, tudo foi feito no painel on line

Comment: Mas você tem gerar a assinatura, "upar", pegar a assinatura que eles preparar colocar na pasta do MacOS, autenticar pelo XCode, ai sim você vai ver os profiles. Não é tudo pelo painel online.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, então, vc diz gerar o .p12, correto? Ao gerar o .p12 eu já coloquei na pasta do projeto, mas confesso que fiz algo errado. É minha primeira vez com a Apple e Mac e estou apanhando.

Answer (score 0):

Olá @pnet!

Este problema que você está tendo diz respeito aos certificados. Para se publicar aplicativos em um dispositivo real, você precisa criar um certificado do tipo AdHoc(caso seja debug, o mesmo deve possuir o aparelho que está sendo feio o deploy autorizado). Tudo é feito em no [ambiente de desenvolvimento da Apple](https://developer.apple.com/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso o `Signinig Profile` selecionado é incorreto para o tipo de publicação, você precisa selecionar algo como "Distribution > Ad-Hoc" que ficará disponível apos vc configurar e baixar o certificado citado anteriormente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs-1. Você pode deixar Tanto o Signing quanto o Provisioning Profile como Auto quando se tem somente uma conta vinculada ao Visual Studio, pois a própria IDE irá fazer o match do profile correto.

Obs-2. Certifique-se de que você está selecionando a arquitetura correta para o build e o dispositivo destino(32 ou 64 bits)

Feito isso você conseguirá realizar o deploy sem problema